# Displaying random numbers with a DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf, random, mvvm

I've been looking for an answer but none seem to fit my question.

I am trying to adapt the **MvVM** method, but I dont think I fully understand it..

I'm trying to create an RPM display in WPF.

I want it to display an number (between 0-3000) and update this number every second (into a `TextBlock`).

I have created a new class where I try to create a DispatcherTimer and Random generator and then put that in the UI TextBlock.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Aldeba.UI.WpfClient
{
    public class GenerateRpm
    {
        public GenerateRpm()
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)
            };
            timer.Start();
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }
        public int RandomValue()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int RandomRpm = random.Next(0, 3001);
            return RandomRpm;
        }
        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

            GenerateRpm rpm = new GenerateRpm();
            mainWindow.RpmDisplayLabel.Text = rpm.RandomValue().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

My MainWindow.xaml.cs looks like...

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
            this.DataContext = new GenerateRpm();
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to add datacontext to all classes I want to access (for bindings for an example)?

This is the MainWindow where I want the Rpm displayed in the second `TextBlock`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="RPM:" Style="{StaticResource RpmDisplay}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="RpmDisplayLabel" Text="{Binding }" Style="{StaticResource RpmDisplay}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

What am I missing and/ or doing wrong to be able to do this?

Comment: `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();` in the Tick handler makes no sense. GenerateRpm should expose and update a public property that the view would bind to. Also move `Random random = new Random();` out of the RandomValue, and make it a class member.

Comment: And `GenerateRpm rpm = new GenerateRpm();` inside the Tick handler is also nonsense. And how is `TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)` supposed to be one second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a view model like shown below, with a public property that is cyclically updated by the timer.

Make sure the property setter fires a change notification, e.g. the `PropertyChanged` event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private int randomRpm;

    public int RandomRpm
    {
        get { return randomRpm; }
        set
        {
            randomRpm = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(RandomRpm)));
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RandomRpm = random.Next(0, 3001);
    }
}
```

Assign an instance of the view model class to the MainWindow's DataContext:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

In the view, bind an element to the view model property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RandomRpm}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I am quite new to programming and I'm still trying to understand the way of binding and accessing. That's why I had the errors you commented on my question.