# datagrid column dosen't get updated

Tags: c#, wpf, random, timer, datagrid

I want to change a column values in a datagrid in a random way each 3 sec.
I refered to a link from here( [Displaying random numbers with a DispatcherTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563469/displaying-random-numbers-with-a-dispatchertimer) ) wish worked when i tested it on a textbox.
But it dosen't update the datagrid column cell only when i double click a cell. 
This is the viewModel, the column i want to change is MarketPrice.

```
 public class PortfolioViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Order order;
    private readonly Random random = new Random();
     public PortfolioViewModel()
    {
        this.PortfolioViewObs = PortfolioView();


        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();

    }

 public ObservableCollection<PortfolioView> PortfolioViewObs
     {
         get;
         set;
     }

 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < this.PortfolioViewObs.Count; i++)
         {
             this.PortfolioViewObs[i].MarketPrice = random.Next(20, 30);    
         }
     }
```

This is MainWindow.xaml

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="PortfolioGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding PortfolioViewObs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="196" Width="630">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Security" Binding="{Binding Symbol}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Owned" Binding="{Binding Owned}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Unit Price" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Total Cost" Binding="{Binding TotalCoast}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Market Price" Binding="{Binding MarketPrice}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="122" Header="Ordered Quantity" Binding="{Binding OrderedQuantity}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

this is mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //ViewModel.PortfolioViewModel vm = new ViewModel.PortfolioViewModel();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel.PortfolioViewModel();

    }
```

PortfolioView is a class implemented in a WCf service

```
[DataContract]
public class PortfolioView
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float Owned { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float TotalCoast { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float MarketPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float OrderedQuantity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public float AvailabeAmount { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.Actually, i just created my model(PortfolioView) class in the wpf client side (not from wcf service as i did ).So it worked perfectly.
Thank you guys for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Store the reference to the `DispatcherTimer` in a field to prevent it from getting garbage collected:

```
public class PortfolioViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Order order;
    private readonly Random random = new Random();
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };

    public PortfolioViewModel()
    {
        this.PortfolioViewObs = new ObservableCollection<PortfolioView>;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PortfolioView> PortfolioViewObs { get; }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.PortfolioViewObs.Count; i++)
        {
            this.PortfolioViewObs[i].MarketPrice = random.Next(20, 30);
        }
    }
}
```

And implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the `PortfolioView` class and make sure that you raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `MarketPrice` property whenever it's set to a new value.

Comment: I did that but nothing chaged, i am still stuck.thanks for your response

Comment: @Mah10: Please show us how you set the `DataContext` of the window then. Also post the acutal implementation of the `PortfolioView` class.

Comment: @Mah10: Edit your question. Don't post the code in the comments field.

Comment: @Mah10: Your `PortfolioView` class does *not* implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so why are you saying that you did what I suggested?